# In C++, I am trying to loop through many objects without recursion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdvector

Lets say I have a vector of a class. This class contains a vector of itself.

```
class A {
    std::vector<A> children;
}
```

How could I loop through the children of A and then loop through those children and so on without using recursion?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be:

```
void traverse(A& a)
{
    std::deque<A*> objs;
    objs.push_back(&a);

    while(!objs.empty())
    {
        A* cur = objs.front();
        objs.pop_front();

        for(auto& obj: cur->children)
        {
            objs.push_back(&obj);
        }

        // cur here will point to every A in turn
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different data structures you could use for this.  For instance, you could use a stack - push each child onto the stack, then pop off the first one.  Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score -1):

You can write this as a loop. If you use recursion, it would look something like this,

```cpp
function recurs(input){
   if (condition)
      return recurs(manipulated_input);
   else
      return answer;
}
```

You can write the same using while condition,

```cpp
function recurs(input){
   while (true){
      if (condition)
          continue;
      else
          return answer;
   }
}
```

You can read further at this link
https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html

Comment: That'd be great, but the question explicitly asks for a non-recursive solution.

Comment: @Chipster could you kindly explain the above solution without recursion. I though my second snippet wasn't doing any recursion.

Comment: Huh, somehow I missed that the second one isn't recursive. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Chipster I've used the same name for both of the functions. :)